# Photos of abused MCU's

Tags: arduino

I am looking for photos of MCUs / Arduinos and the like which have been used in difficult/dirty/challenging environments but still work.

If anyone can point me towards any pics like this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: does my bad soldering count?

Comment: How about sticking electronics in animals?

Comment: @Kellenjb - ..... are you saying you do that?

Comment: @Fake Name, yeah, all FDA approved though.

Comment: @Kellenjb - are you talking about those ID chips they can embed in your dog's ear, that kind of thing?

Comment: @JustJeff more complex then that. Don't want to release any trade secrets though.

Comment: @Kellenjb: Will a photo release a trade secret, or is it possible to get one (or X-ray) with it?

Answer (score 5):

Any "harsh environment" will destroy a stock Arduino.  They utterly lack any sort of protection.

A company I used to work for would get warranty returns for vehicle data computers that were half filled with water but still fine electrically as the board was conformal coated with a silicone resin.

In any case, outside of temperature swings (and occasionally, [radiation](http://www.atmel.com/products/radhard/default.asp)), the MCU does not, nor is expected to, survive.  It is the job of enclosures and coatings to protect it from everything else, such as moisture, chemicals, and thermal shock.

Answer (score 2):

I'll see if I can get some good pictures of the inside of my Roomba, but I did just clean it out.  Trust me, it's filthy in there.